# Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '

Tags: c, twitter-bootstrap

> Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E'.': 
>   DeviceException - Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) is not running. Retry after starting Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) from the services management console.  ParkeerplaatsenApp
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error       Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found. Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) is not running. Retry after starting Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) from the services management console.   ParkeerplaatsenApp

These are the errors I get when trying to run my Project on my Windows 10 pc.
It's a application about parking spots if this should matter.

Comment: so, the error messages say that some service is not started.  So start that service, then try running your application again.

Comment: @user3629249 What do you mean by 'start the service'?

Comment: given: ` Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) is not running. ` is saying some `service` is not running.  so the `service` needs to be started.  I do not (if I can avoid it) use windows, so do not remember the exact details of how to start a service.  however, this should help you: <https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htkdfk18%28v=vs.110%29.aspx>

Comment: Page is missing 'link incorrect'.

Comment: That is odd.  I got to the linked page by googling for 'how to start a service in windows' and opened the 'hit' with the title `How to: Start Services - MSDN - Microsoft`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had that problem and found that this can have several fixes.

First try check if you have that service installed, open PowerShell window and type:

```
Get-Service -Name *USB*
Status   Name               DisplayName
Stopped  IpOverUsbSvc       Windows Phone IP over USB Transport...
```

If you get answer that service is installed but stopped restart it.

```
Start-Service IpOverUsbSvc
```

If no answer try to install windows phone 8 SDK, restart computer try to check again if service is installed then if it is you can continue with debug.

If no try to input this registry values to your system registry.
Copy paste this below and save as a 'reg' file. Then double click and add, restart computer, check if you have service.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\IpOverUsbSvc]
"DisplayName"="Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc)"
"Description"="Enables communication between Windows Phone SDK and Windows Phone device. If the service is stopped, application deployment and debugging will fail on device."
"Type"=dword:00000010
"Start"=dword:00000002
"ErrorControl"=dword:00000000
"ImagePath"=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,\
  6d,00,20,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,\
  00,5c,00,43,00,6f,00,6d,00,6d,00,6f,00,6e,00,20,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,\
  73,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,53,\
  00,68,00,61,00,72,00,65,00,64,00,5c,00,50,00,68,00,6f,00,6e,00,65,00,20,00,\
  54,00,6f,00,6f,00,6c,00,73,00,5c,00,43,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,43,00,6f,00,6e,\
  00,5c,00,31,00,31,00,2e,00,30,00,5c,00,62,00,69,00,6e,00,5c,00,49,00,70,00,\
  4f,00,76,00,65,00,72,00,55,00,73,00,62,00,53,00,76,00,63,00,2e,00,65,00,78,\
  00,65,00,22,00,00,00
"ObjectName"="LocalSystem"
```

If this also didn't help yuu check if you have executable under directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\CoreCon\11.0\bin\IpOverUsbSvc.exe
```

Try to install service from normal command prompt using installutil program like this.

```
installutil IpOverUsbSvc.exe
```

Hope that helps.